# Pact ToDo MVC - No handler accepted "/" Message in Browser

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, pact-lang

After launching, https://github.com/kadena-io/pact-todomvc in the browser I get the error No handler accepted "/" . I've tried toggling the server.conf file to both localhost:9000 and 8080.

Is there something else I need to config? I've followed the readme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

server.conf file configures the port for the pact server, but the web app will be running on a node server and the port for this is defined in the server.js file.

If you set the port in server.conf file at 9001 and go to localhost:8080, you'll be able to see the app running unless you're already using the port or have a preconfigured port for node.

Hope this works!

Comment: i realized i was getting an error that was related to the webpack plugin so i added installation instructions as a PR to the repo readme https://github.com/kadena-io/pact-todomvc/pull/11